# Self-Join with Subquery in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am a SQL noob in need of some help with a specific query using the NYC 2013 Taxi Trips Dataset [located here](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/833682135931:nyctaxi.trip_data).

I want to analyze dropoffs at JFK Airport, but want to build my query so that I can include the next subsequent pickup that a taxi does after dropping off someone at the airport.

This query gets me all the trips at the airport for a given day:

```
SELECT * FROM [833682135931:nyctaxi.trip_data] 
WHERE DATE(pickup_datetime) = '2013-05-01'
  AND FLOAT(pickup_latitude) < 40.651381
  AND FLOAT(pickup_latitude) > 40.640668
  AND FLOAT(pickup_longitude) < -73.776283
  AND FLOAT(pickup_longitude) > -73.794694
```

I want to join the dataset with itself to add next_pickup_time, next_pickup_lat, and next_pickup_lon values for each row.

To do this, I assume I need a correlated subquery, but don't know where to start building it out because the subquery is based on the outer query.

It needs to search for trips with the same medallion, on the same day, and with a pickup time later than the current airport dropoff, then limit 1... Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you all the dropoffs with next pickups

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT medallion,
          dropoff_datetime,
          dropoff_longitude,
          dropoff_latitude,
          LEAD(pickup_datetime, 1, "") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion
                                             ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_datetime,
          LEAD(pickup_longitude, 1, "0.0") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion
                                                 ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_longitude,
          LEAD(pickup_latitude, 1, "0.0") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion
                                                ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_latitude
   FROM [833682135931:nyctaxi.trip_data]) d
WHERE date(next_datetime)=date(dropoff_datetime)
  AND DATE(dropoff_datetime) = '2013-05-01'
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_latitude) < 40.651381
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_latitude) > 40.640668
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_longitude) < -73.776283
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_longitude) > -73.794694
```

Comment: This is looking at pickups at the airport and getting the next pickup.  I need dropoffs at the airport and the next pickup.  I swapped out all of the pickups for dropoffs except the ones in the LEAD statements, but now it just queries forever...  Nevermind, it worked, it just took 400 seconds!

Comment: This compiles in the sub query for each row the next pickup. Then in the outer query you restrict to the same day, to the JFK pickup and filter to the date given. Sometimes on BQ a query can taken 5-6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

consider using the LAG window function instead of self join

Comment: I don't think this would work because the next trip for a vehicle is not the next row in the dataset, there are 13,000 taxis with trips all in one table...

Answer (score 1):

I think that N.N. has the right idea, except that you want LEAD instead of LAG to get the next pickup.  For example, this query will produce the next pickup time, lat and long after a pickup at JFK.

```
SELECT
    medallion,
    pickup_datetime,
    pickup_longitude,
    pickup_latitude,
    LEAD(pickup_datetime, 1, "") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_datetime,
    LEAD(pickup_longitude, 1, "0.0") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_longitude,
    LEAD(pickup_latitude, 1, "0.0") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_latitude
FROM [833682135931:nyctaxi.trip_data]
WHERE DATE(pickup_datetime) = '2013-05-01'
  AND FLOAT(pickup_latitude) < 40.651381
  AND FLOAT(pickup_latitude) > 40.640668
  AND FLOAT(pickup_longitude) < -73.776283
  AND FLOAT(pickup_longitude) > -73.794694;
```

Any time you can avoid a self-join, it's good to do so.

Comment: Thanks!  So I tested this out and I still don't think we're quite there yet... I want cabs that dropoff at the airport and their next pickup, and this query has all pickups.  I am trying to tweak it on my own but am not having much luck.  I realize my original query also had this error... all of those pickups should be dropoffs

Comment: So I don't think LEAD will actually work because the WHERE clause is already filtering for dropoff lat lon near the airport.  If the next pickup is not at the airport, there will not be a LEAD row with the same medallion, and this query will throw in 0 for the lat lon

Comment: this query refers only to dropoffs in JFK (even if they are not the following trip). you'll need to first do the "Lead", in a subquery,  and afterwards filter it using your where in a parent query.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked, modified from Pentium10's answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT medallion,
          dropoff_datetime,
          dropoff_longitude,
          dropoff_latitude,
          LEAD(pickup_datetime, 1, "") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion
                                             ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_datetime,
          LEAD(pickup_longitude, 1, "0.0") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion
                                                 ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_longitude,
          LEAD(pickup_latitude, 1, "0.0") OVER (PARTITION BY medallion
                                                ORDER BY pickup_datetime) AS next_latitude
   FROM [833682135931:nyctaxi.trip_data]) d
WHERE date(next_datetime)=date(dropoff_datetime)
  AND DATE(dropoff_datetime) = '2013-05-01'
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_latitude) < 40.651381
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_latitude) > 40.640668
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_longitude) < -73.776283
  AND FLOAT(dropoff_longitude) > -73.794694
```